# Contact Form 7 Redirect Code Not Redirecting

Tags: javascript, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have 2 contact forms that should redirect to 2 different 'thank you' pages.

There is no data on this in the Stackoverflow community.

This is the code I use when wanting to redirect 2 different forms. This code is not working:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cf7_thank_you_redirect' ); 

function cf7_thank_you_redirect() { 

?> <script type="text/javascript"> 

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 

if ( '936' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { location = 'http://wp-phd.com/thank-you-1'; } 

else if ( '937' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { location = 'http://wp-phd.com/thank-you-2'; } 

else { // do nothing } }, false ); 

</script> 
<?php 
}
```

---

I expect the code to redirect to the 'thank you' page when the user clicks submit

Comment: Try using `wpcf7submit` instead of `wpcf7mailsent`.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this. You are using `location` to try and redirect to another URL but in javascript `window.location.href` is used for redirection.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cf7_thank_you_redirect' ); 

function cf7_thank_you_redirect() { 

?> <script type="text/javascript"> 

document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) { 

if ( '936' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { window.location.href = 'http://wp-phd.com/thank-you-1'; } 

else if ( '937' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { window.location.href = 'http://wp-phd.com/thank-you-2'; } 

else { // do nothing } }, false ); 

</script> 
<?php 
}
```

Comment: This answer may solve the issue, but you should explain why it does - don't just post code.